# selenium rc turn off proxy firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy, selenium-rc

My issue is caused by incorrect 'proxy' settings in Firefox so I want to disable the proxy in the profile that Selenium uses for my tests.

Currently my profile looks for the local proxy settings file by default:

file:///C:/Users/%username%/AppData/Local/Temp/customProfileDir536e1d9817834e4e838cad55697fc909/proxy.pac

That file contains these 3 lines:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return 'PROXY localhost:4444; DIRECT';
}
```

If during the tests I open the settings and set 'no proxy', the app starts working fine. How can I make the tests always launch with the 'no proxy' setting?

I tried to use the `-avoidProxy` flag when running the Selenium server but that hasn't helped. I also tried using a separate profile for tests but Selenium overrides its settings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new firefox browser profile & set the preferences in it as per your requirement.

Start selenium server with this profile using the switch 
 `-firefoxProfileTemplate <path_to_firefox>`

Comment: thanks for reply, man. yep, I tried to configure separate profile to 'no proxy', but selenium overrides it as well as the default profile